# Speed control effect doesn't change the length of video strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I ran into some confusing behaviour of the speed control effect.
I've loaded a whole strip of video and applied the effect setting it to a 2x speedup 
(in two variants - with the default "stretch to the input length" and "Scale to length").

I expected to see the reduced length of strip, but it appears to have no influence on the length. On the other hand, the video sequencer shows that after some frame, the picture doesn't change while marker is moving. Do I have to calculate this frame manually to insert a new video strip?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you add a `Speed Control` strip, `Stretch to input strip length` is enabled by default.  That gives you the ability to change the length of your video strip (aka "input strip") and the speed will automatically adjust.  For example, if you make your video strip half as long, the speed will be twice as fast.

You also can set the parameter `Multiply Speed`.  This will change the speed of your video without changing the length.  For example, you can set this to `2.0`, but since the video finishes twice as fast yet the length stays the same, the video will run out before the end of the strip, and so for the remainder of the strip, Blender will just display the last frame.

Comment: very confusing, still don't get it every time...